# How to override WindowsPhone dark theme by light

Tags: windows-phone-7

Any idea on over-riding the dark theme without copy the default design/ThemeResources.xml file?

Comment: Bad idea, don't do it. OLED displays are not backlit. Power consumption is proportional to pixel brightness. This is why the black background is recommended.

Comment: My application background is white image, hence the controls(since it uses Phone resource dictionary) are displays fine in light theme, where as switch to dark themes leads controls are invisible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want  to override the resources file the alternative is to create your own styles for every control that you use and apply that to each instance of each control.
Overriding the resources fiel is easier. ;)

Comment: My application contains several pages and controls. Hence it take some huge time. While analyzing on this, i found link "http://wp7wonders.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/create-a-theme-for-your-windows-phone-7-application/" they suggest to copy the values from default themeresource.xml file from WP installed path. This resource file is copyrighted for "Microsoft premium shared source license agreement". Can we copy this into our application?

Comment: @bala_winwin If you have legal questions you should ask a lawyer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the useful link http://www.designersilverlight.com/2011/01/17/theme-forcing-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight/