# Windows Phone 7.1 Light/Dark themes management

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

How does exactly work themes switching in application? What if I override the default styles? Can I also define different styles for light and dark themes separately? Why the icons colos get changed - i.e. the black background of icons changes into white if the theme is set to Dark. Will it also be changed to white if I override the background style of application bar to white explicitly? How can I make sure nothing gets changed and my app looks the same in Light and Dark themes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen these?

Theme Overview for Windows Phone

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402557(v=vs.105).aspx

Theme Resources for Windows Phone

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552(v=vs.105).aspx

How to: Apply Theme Resources for Windows Phone

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769545(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [PhoneThemeManager](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/) from Jeff Wilcox for theme overriding works!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is better to have the same UX across all the Windows Phone application when it comes to light/dark theme support, but I agree that sometimes it is really needed to override the theme.

You can probably find more information in this thread: [How to override WindowsPhone dark theme by light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211635/how-to-override-windowsphone-dark-theme-by-light)

and also previously I was using this tutorial to customize light and dark themes:
http://blog.richardszalay.com/2011/06/11/practical-support-for-light-dark-themes-on-windows-phone-7/