# Night mode and Microsoft's submission requirements

Tags: windows-phone-7

I heard that Microsoft refuse app's which unreadable in the "night mode" whatever it is? I mean when the phone goes into night mode all the color fonts are changed and that makes app unusable, then they reject the app.

I nave to submit RSS app and I do not know even what I have to watch out about that night mode. Please introduce me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that what you mean is "light theme" mode. There are a lot of useful comments about this on this other thread. [Windows Phone 7.1 Light/Dark themes management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181350/windows-phone-7-1-light-dark-themes-management).

From my own personal experience, this is a bit of a headache. If your app isn't very stylistic, try to use the built-in colours for all your controls and whatever you do don't put an image background on it (that was my downfall).